# Is it possible to run a logit model with only ones and no zeros?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, mlogit

For my thesis I'm trying to build a model which predicts the ones of my sample correctly via a logit model. First, I encountered the problem that python does not have a logit model, but only a logistic model. But with this logistic model I get an error in the code below `[logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)]`.
My error is the following: This Solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data. Well, my data only consists of ones, and contains no zeros. So this error is correct, in the sense it should be this way. Is there a way to get around the error so I can continue my analysis, without having to look for all kinds of data to also get zeros, which will be way too time consuming due to the complexity of my database.

I have already tried to fix it, but could not find anything that solves this problem yet. Removing the line which provides the error was also not an option, because this created a lot of new problems further on in the code.

```
feature_cols =['RSIZE','EXRETAVG','NIMTAAVG','TLMTA','CASHMTA','SIGMA','PRICE','MB']
X = df[feature_cols]
y = df.Bankrupt
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=logreg.predict(X_test)



cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cnf_matrix)
class_names=[0,1] # name  of classes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names)
sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(cnf_matrix), annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu" ,fmt='g')
ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title('Confusion matrix', y=1.1)
plt.ylabel('Actual label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Precision:",metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Recall:",metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
y_pred_proba = logreg.predict_proba(X_test)[::,1]
fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_test,  y_pred_proba)
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)
plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label="data 1, auc="+str(auc))
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense to me. You wouldn't train a supervised model in such a situation, because the model would only ever predict one class.

Comment: True, I am currently only trying to predict the ones and not the zeros. But it is still possible that when back-testing the model out of sample it predicts a zero, while in reality it was a one.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that **you always need more than one class**.

What any model does is try to identify how each variable (feature, your X) affect the outcome of a dependent variable (Y, your categories). Now, if you only have one category in your dependent variable then no matter what value and combination of values your Xs will have you will always get the same outcome.
This means that if you train your model on one class only (your ones), when testing it will always return a 1 (and you basically wouldn't need to train and test anything).

A toy example could be: `Y` is if the observation defaulted within a year. `X` pure probability of default computed through some kind of model.

Let then say that you would be happy if your model would predict a `Y=1` (default within one year) if `X>0.5`.
You then subsample only the cases where `Y=1` and train your model. You will get a simple flat line (`Y=1`) no matter what value `X` will take.
This implies that when testing your model, no matter what value `X` will have and what the real outcome of your dependent variable is, you will always estimate `Y=1`.

Comment: It is working now, thank you Gio. It toke me a while to extend my database but it works.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed your problem